# How to check it was clicked on one of the children of a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this script:

```
$('body').click(function(evt){
   var all_childs=$("#menu-js").find('*');
    console.log(all_childs);
    if(evt.target.id == "menu-js"){   //here should change condition
        console.log(evt.target.id);
        return;
    }else{
        if($('#menu-left').is(':visible'))
        {
            $("#menu-left").hide();
        }else{
            if(evt.target.id == "cake") {
                $("#menu-left").show();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

what I want is to check if it was clicked on one of the elements of `"all_child"`

And I put the link to my website in order to better inspect code

[link](http://dg-design.ch/bagel/)

How can I put this condition?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

[sample](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YqyoWY)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div id="menu-js">
  <ul id="menu-left">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>  
</div>  

<button id="cake">SHOW MENU</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check it like this (updated as per your requirement)

```
var $target = $(evt.target || evt.srcElement);
// check if the current target has a parent with id 'menu-js'
if ($target.parents("#menu-js").length > 0) {
  if ($('#menu-left').is(':visible')) {
    $("#menu-left").hide();
  }
} else if (evt.target.id == "cake") {
  $("#menu-left").show();
}
```

Comment: I'll make an example and post the link here

Comment: Sure sure, but I think you can achieve by this code what you asked in the question.

Comment: what happens if we give to the default menu display: none?

Comment: Even if you give 'menu-left' default display as none, the code will work fine

Answer (score 0):

This is fully works as you wanted !

Here is the link to: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f7c95urt/10/)

```
$('body').click(function(e) {

    var target = $(e.target);
        console.log(target.context);
        console.log(target.is(':visible'))

    if(target.context.id == "menu-js"){   //here should change condition
                alert(target.context.id);
    }else{
                    if($('#menu-left').is(':visible')){
             $("#menu-left").hide();
          }else{
             if(target.context.id == "cake") {
                $("#menu-left").show();
            }
          }
        }
});
```